# Represent the binding offset next to the page margin as a shaded region

Tags: pdftex, geometry

I am using the `bindingoffset` command of the `geometry` package to shift the page margin in order to compensate for the actual binding. Is there any way to represent this offset from `bindingoffset` as a shaded region on the page? I'd like to have it visible on the page to be able to distinguish it from the actual page margin.

Below is a mock-up of what I'm trying to achieve. The shaded region represents the `bindingoffset`'s length e.g. 10mm.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with `eso-pic`. Here is an example with two-sided printing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=2cm, bindingoffset=1cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageLowerLeft{\color{Gainsboro}\ifnumodd{\arabic{page}}{}{\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm}}\rule{10mm}{\paperheight}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've tried your example, but it does not work using `\pagenumbering{gobble}` and `\pagenumbering{roman}`.

Comment: @Anonymous: I didn't think of this problem. I've modified the parity test in my code, and for me there's no problem now.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm! This is exactly what I was looking for. Not that it matters, but would there be a way to change the shaded region into a stripe pattern (as seen in the mock-up above), instead of a single colour?

Comment: I suppose so (although your pattern is not quite regular), with TiKZ or pstricks. I don't know well enough the former, but it would not be so difficult with pstricks: instead of inserting a simple coloured LaTeX rule, inserting a \psframe with a certain filling pattern would do the trick.